# How to load all products with certain type - e.g. all configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-1, products

How can I get a collection of all products from a specific type example given: "configurable" ?

I want to show the name of all products of type configurable for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('type_id','configurable');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . "</br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!